# Как в ларавел в классе валидации сделать проверку полей относительно друг друга?

Tags: laravel

Как в классе валидации request, сделать правило, чтоб сравнивать два поля: чтоб первое не могло быть больше второго, а второе не могло быть меньше первого. Что то вроде этого:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
  'price_min' => 'required|integer|min:5',
  'price_max' => 'required|integer|min:5',
           ];
}
```

Как добавить правила, чтоб price_min не могло быть больше price_max и соответственно price_max не могло быть меньше price_min?

Answer (score 0):

Вобшем, решение gt:field и lte:field.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]